# Permanently add Libraries in Python

Tags: python

I have this simple piece of code in a file:

```
frame = DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4),
    index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=2, freq='W-WED'),
    columns=['Colorado', 'Texas', 'New York', 'Ohio'])
```

When I try to run the file I get error messages telling me that it doesn't know what to do with DataFrame, np, or pd. I can fix this easily by adding in "

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

My question: is there a way that I can avoid having to import these libraries within every file that I want to use those tools?

I had imported them in the command line before running this file but this didn't seem to make a difference.

New to Python. Thanks in advance for the help.

Using Python 2 in the Canopy editor.

Comment: Are you just looking at doing this for interactive sessions? If so, you may want to look at the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable. And, even more, you may want to look at IPython.

Comment: But still, each _module_ (as opposed to script) is expected to be self-contained, with its own globals. While you can fake your way around that (e.g., by pushing stuff from globals into builtins), you usually shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if you are going to use a package/module, then you *should*<sup>*</sup> import it in every module that needs it.  While it might be a little annoying writing the same imports over and over, it's better in the long run because it makes your code a lot more *clear*.  e.g. you know what `np` or `DataFrame` is and where it comes from.

<sup>I suppose that it's worth noting that you probably *can* get around this requirement by writing your own [import hook](http://xion.org.pl/2012/05/06/hacking-python-imports/), but . . .That's way too complicated a thing to do just to enable you to write code that will likely confuse your co-workers :-)</sup>

---

<sup><sup>*</sup>There are some [conveniences](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) that you can use to get around this in the interactive interpretter, but not in anything that gets imported via the normal mechanisms.</sup>